# Roles y seguridad en php con Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, seguridad

Estoy realizando una app en php con Symfony.

Intento limitar el acceso a algunas rutas de mi aplicación mediante el "access_control" del archivo "security.yaml"

```
access_control:
        { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_DISPACHER }
```

Pero al hacerlo me lanza el siguiente error:

**Tipo no válido para la ruta "security.access_control.path". Se esperaba "matriz", pero se obtuvo "cadena"**

En la base de datos el campo roles tiene ["ROLE_DISPACHER"]

No se de donde puede venir el error, he probado todo lo que pude encontrar por la documentación de Symfony y por diferentes sitios de internet. Creo que es algo sencillo, pero no logro ver que es.

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error donde el path, estás declarando en formato cadena y espera un array. Para declarar arrays en un archivo yaml necesitas usar el siguiente formato (faltaba el guión).

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_DISPACHER }
```

Comment: Solucionado con tu respuesta. Gracias!